# Вывести список конкурсантов в соответствии с выбранным подразделением?

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

Я новичок в веб разработке и использую **framework Django**!
Прошу вас помочь или направить на правильный путь.
Необходимо реализовать выборку конкурсантов по выбранному из выпадающего списка подразделению.
Модель contestant имеет вторичный ключ к модели division
В template реализован вывод двух форм:

```
class divisionForm(ModelForm): # Подразделения
    class Meta:
        model = division
        fields = ['name_division']
        widgets = {
            "name_division": Select(attrs={}),
        }

class contestantForm(ModelForm): # Конкурсанты
    class Meta:
        model = contestant
        fields = ['name_contestant']
        widgets = {
            "name_contestant": Select(attrs={}),
        }
```

По итогу страница выглядит примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На сколько я понял, Django выступает в роли сервера и при загрузке страницы отдает данные обработанные во views.py, **как реализовать вывод всех конкурсантов из выбранного в template подразделения?** **уже на стороне клиента без POST и GET запросов.**
Есть ли у Вас пример javascript по взаимодействию с Django на подобную тему?